# Textbox in ContextMenu loses focus on mouse move

Tags: wpf, textbox, focus, contextmenu

I have a Textbox withing the ControlTemplate of a MenuItem, which is inside a ContextMenu. The Textbox works well and I can type in it properly. But if I move the mouse over any of the other menu items in the context menu, they claim focus and I lose focus from the textbox. At this point I have to click back into the textbox to continue typing.

Is there a pattern or accepted method of resolving this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please post some code? I have tried your implementation and I don't have this problem

Comment: We have restyled the menu items significantly, so its kind of hard to demo here. If you're not seeing an issue, maybe its because of our styling.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to take back focus, you can type as below.

```
textBox.CaptureMouse();
textBox.ReleaseMouseCapture();
```

> I think it can catch focus to textbox.

Comment: The problem is that the textbox loses focus. I don't see how CaptureMouse can help because it can still lose focus again.

Comment: After naming textBox, can you use CaptureMouse and ReleaseMouseCapture code at menuItem_PreviewGotKeyboardFocus?

Answer (score 0):

Well after trying a few different things, I got something to work:

For all other menu items that can capture focus (on mouse enter), set e.Handled = true for the PriviewGoTKeyboardFocus event:

```
void menuItem_PreviewGotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
  e.Handled = true;
}
```

One can do this automatically from a window base class by looping through all menu items in a context menu. This requires hijacking the tag for those menuitems in which you insert the textbox.

```
void contextMenu_Opened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

{
  ContextMenu contextMenu = sender as ContextMenu;
  foreach (FrameworkElement frameworkElement in contextMenu.Items)
  {
    if (frameworkElement is MenuItem)
    {
      MenuItem menuItem = (frameworkElement as MenuItem);
      if (!(menuItem.Tag != null && menuItem.Tag.ToString() == "MaintainFocus"))
        menuItem.PreviewGotKeyboardFocus += new KeyboardFocusChangedEventHandler(menuItem_PreviewGotKeyboardFocus);
    }
  }
}
void contextMenu_Closed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  ContextMenu contextMenu = sender as ContextMenu;
  foreach (FrameworkElement frameworkElement in contextMenu.Items)
  {
    if (frameworkElement is MenuItem)
    {
      MenuItem menuItem = (frameworkElement as MenuItem);
      if (!(menuItem.Tag != null && menuItem.Tag.ToString() == "MaintainFocus"))
        menuItem.PreviewGotKeyboardFocus -= menuItem_PreviewGotKeyboardFocus;
    }
  }
}
```